# Need to extend elisp function

Tags: elisp

All,

I must suck at eLisp. Banged this first function out in no time.

```
(defun sort-lines-reverse (beg end)
  "sort lines in reverse order"
   (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (point-min) (point-max))))
   (if (and beg end)
       (sort-lines 1 beg end))
   )
```

works perfectly. Hosed this next one

```
(defun sort-numeric-fields-reverse (field beg end)
  "sort numeric fields in reverse order"
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (read-number "Field number: " 1) (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (read-number "Field number: " 1) (point-min) (point-max)))
   (message "calling if")
   (if (and beg end)
       ((message "inside if")
        (sort-numeric-fields field beg end)
        (reverse-region beg end))
     )
   ))
```

No runs no hits no errors. Don't see a single message displayed in messages. I do get my field number prompt.

A snippet of randomly generated test data if one so wishes.

```
8       412086510
8       744308263
8       1482781895
8       995992436
1       1021762533
1       897682569
1       963686690
1       166565707
1       2096612583
1       829723388
1       587753131
1       264251710
32      139885828
32      781244288
```

Adding insult to injury in my KDE Neon environment the C-M-x to bring up the lisp debugger doesn't do squat.

The only real difference between these two functions is in this one I have to prompt for a field number. Inside the if I run 2 functions instead of one. After getting the first one to work the second should have been a cakewalk.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `interactive` form encompasses the *entire function body*.  As that is multiple forms, and only a single form is expected/evaluated, everything after the `if` is being ignored.  The arguments are thus obtained and then the function immediately returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- missing ) at the end of interactive, after (if (use-region-p) ...
- missing progn in (if (and beg end)...
  (progn is superfluous because if has been replaced by when.)

Corrected version:

```
(defun sort-numeric-fields-reverse (field beg end)
  "sort numeric fields in reverse order"
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (read-number "Field number: " 1) (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (read-number "Field number: " 1) (point-min) (point-max))))
  (message "calling if")
  (when (and beg end)
    (message "inside if")
    (sort-numeric-fields field beg end)
    (reverse-region beg end)))
```

EDIT: Code changed: if-progn replaced with when according to hint from @phils.

Hint: using an adequate editor makes the typing easy and gives you control over parentheses.

Comment: Of course you can use `(when foo ...)` instead of `(if foo (progn ...))`

Comment: I was using Emacs, just don't really care to work in any form of lisp is the problem. Thank you. Hopefully the site will eventually let me flag this as accepted.